# JQ Mobile - Transitioning BACK to a page & want to do something but can't figure out what event to call

Tags: jquery, mobile

On my main page, when it goes live

```
$('#mainPage').live('pagecreate', function (event) {

    if (window.openDatabase) {
        //createDatabase();
        //etc
```

I list a table out to the screen... I have a Maintenance button/page that allows me to edit, delete some entries.

I want to be able to re-list that table on the main page when I click BACK from my maintenance page (since that table has most likely changed) but I cannot figure out what event is called when a page is transitioned too...

Nothing happens in the .live('pagecreate' -- event... I tried pageinit... I am missing something here.

Help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I found:

1. I was using the data-rel="back" on my button which kept taking me to
   index.html rather than the div name (#mainPage)... so I removed the
   back behavior because I really didnt need it. (not sure what I would
   do if I did)
2. read more of the jq mobile docs (imagine that) and found this rather verbose way:

   $(document).bind("pagebeforechange", function (e, data) {

   ```
       // We only want to handle changePage() calls where the caller is
       // asking us to load a page by URL.
       if (typeof data.toPage === "string") {

           // We are being asked to load a page by URL, but we only
           // want to handle URLs that request the data for a specific
           // category.
           var u = $.mobile.path.parseUrl(data.toPage);
           var re = /^#mainPage/;

           if (u.hash.search(re) !== -1) {
               listZooAnimals();
           }
       }
   });
   ```

This just feels like serious overkill and that I might still be missing some easier way of doing this.